# Retina support in QML

Tags: macos, qt, qml, retina-display

How to use retina support in QML? How to choose correct sizes and correct resolution of images?
App needs to work on retina and not-retina devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very good and comprehensive article on that topic by Morten Johan Sørvig can be found [here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/04/25/retina-display-support-for-mac-os-ios-and-x11/).

Qt Quick 2 and the Qt Quick Controls work well out-of-the box when it comes to hdpi support.
An important thing to take into consideration is raster content and as explained in the article:

> As an app developer you have two options: (ignoring the “do-nothing”
>   option)
>
> ```
> Replace existing raster content with a high-resolution version
> Provide separate high-resolution content
> ```
>
> The first option is convenient since there is only one version of each
>   resource. However, you may find (or your designer will tell you) that
>   resources like icons look best when created for a specific resolution.
>   To facilitate this, Qt as adopted the “@2x” convention for image
>   filenames:
>
> foo.png foo@2x.png
>
> High-resolution content can be provided side-by-side with the
>   originals. The “@2x” version will be loaded automatically when needed
>   by the QML Image element and QIcon:
>
> Image { source = “foo.png” } QIcon icon(“foo.png”)
>
> (remember to set AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps for QIcon)

---

Another thread on the topic [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/44805/).

Comment: What's about sizes (window size, button size, etc)?