# HDPI/Retina icons in PyQt4 or PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, retina-display, pyqt5

I am working on a Python application that uses Qt as the GUI framework. As part of this, I want to include buttons that have icons. However, I cannot find a way to make the icons appear sharp on HiDPI/Retina displays. The icon I am working with is:

[image: icon]

which is provided as a PNG file which I will call `open.png`.

I now have the following code to test what a button with this icon looks like in PyQt4 and PyQt5:

```
QT = 5

if QT == 4:
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QIcon
elif QT == 5:
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton

app = QApplication([''])
main = QMainWindow()
main.setWindowTitle("Qt {0}".format(QT))
icon = QIcon('open.png')
button = QPushButton()
button.setIcon(icon)
button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30,30))
main.setCentralWidget(button)
main.show()
app.exec_()
```

The results are the following:

**PyQt4**

[image: PyQt4 screenshot]

**PyQt5**

[image: PyQt5 screenshot]

In both cases, the icon resolution is clearly lower than e.g. the title of the window (which shows the native resolution)

Is there a way to make either or both PyQt4 and PyQt5 show an icon at the full resolution of the display?

Comment: May be this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165823/retina-support-in-qml. In other words, did you set AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps flag?

Comment: Indeed, that does the trick, thanks!